# How to determine this font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize, computer-modern

I cannot figure out what font is being used in this screenshot:[image]

It's not, by any means, Latin Modern nor the normal Computer Modern. There's a trick or something fishy going on here. I did the research in Adobe as mentioned on other posts here:
[image]

[image]

Does anybody know what type of Computer Modern font type might be being used here?

Comment: your font lists show normal computer modern fonts  (plus hevetica and Roboto and a few others)

Comment: What made you think this wasn't Computer Modern? I don't see anything here that doesn't look like CM (although the incorrect quotes hurt my eyes).

Comment: @DonHosek With respect to the quotes, I think the author knew what he was doing, he seems to be kinda smart :) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Walsh

Comment: @Delan smart doesn't mean that you do proper quotes when you type. I've seen a lot of LaTeX from smart authors which is atrocious in its formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [this list](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf) helpful.  The `cmsy` font is Computer Modern Math Symbols, where the numbers are the different optical sizes for regular text and superscripts/subscripts.  The `cmtt` family is Computer Modern Typewriter Text, the default `\ttfamily`.  These also come in different optical sizes, so the document might have been compiled with the `12pt` option and then used a typewriter font in smaller sizes, such as the abstract and footnotes.

Several of the others are from [`amsfonts`.](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf)  The `msam` and `msbm` fonts are math symbol fonts, of which `msbm` includes blackboard bold, and `eufm` is Euler Fraktur.  These also come in different optical sizes.

These are the font families loaded by `amsfonts` and `amssymb`.  The abbreviations are so cryptic because, historically, every font file had to pack its name within the eight-character limit, plus extension, of MS-DOS, including its weight, shape, optical size and family.

It’s impossible to say from the screenshot which Type 3 font the document is using, but it’s almost certainly a bitmap font compiled from METAFONT.  The other font families have human-readable names.